# Isolating JS from other JS in the same HTML document

Tags: javascript, namespaces, isolation

Consider this code:

```
<script>var foo = 'bar';</script>
<div id='isolated'>
    <script>console.log(foo)</script>
</div>
```

This will return `'bar'` to the console. However I'd like for `foo` and any other variables declared outside `#isolated` to be `undefined` from within it.

How can this be achieved? A cross-browser, lightweight and native solution would be preferable.

Comment: Maybe look into https://github.com/asvd/jailed or https://github.com/google/caja. Google "in browser js sandbox".

Comment: Don't mix your JS and html code like this. Keep them separate.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how JavaScript works. It doesn't scope itself because of a HTML element block.

You're declaring `foo` at the global scope, simply declare it in the scope that it would only be used when needed. Using ES6 (Harmony), using `let` instead of `var` (proposed, not fully supported) to declare a variable proposes a block level variable instead of a global scoped variable.

As it stands however, JavaScript has no idea `foo` is being logged inside the isolated div unless you use some logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the code in between the first `<script></script>` tag in a function.

```
<script>(function fn(){var foo = 'bar';})();</script>
<div id='isolated'>
    <script>console.log(foo);</script>
</div>
```

This will cause whatever variables you declare to live within the context of this function. They will not be accessible outside this function.

Comment: This will work, however, in the context of the question, `foo` is no longer accessible anywhere, instead of just inside the isolated div.

Answer (score 0):

If you load your isolated code in an iframe and host the code at a different domain the scopes will be separated.  You can then pass messages back and forth between the parent and the iframe via the cross-document messaging services (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)